# Axios request not being made in electron app

Tags: javascript, rest, asynchronous, axios

I am new to javascript async/await etc. The code below has been stripped of any unimportant parts.

The function addAllocationToQueue is invoked from a button press in an electron app. This makes an axios request and creates a new allocation item which belongs to a user. After this has completed, populateAllocationQueue is invoked which updates the DOM to reflect the new allocation item that's been added, but this is where I am having trouble... In this method I am looping through the allocations in the allocationQueue array. for each of the allocations I wish to make a new api call which will return the user that this allocation belongs to, but the problem is that the axios request inside the for loop is not firing.

Am i handling the async functions correctly?

```
const axios = require('axios')

var currentSandboxId = '1';
var allocationQueue = []

const setCurrentSandboxId = async (sbId) => {
  currentSandboxId = sbId;
  const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/allocations/all-for-sandbox/${currentSandboxId}`)
  allocationQueue = response.data
  await populateAllocationQueue()
}

const addAllocationToQueue = async () => {
  const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/allocations/', {
    sandboxId: currentSandboxId,
    branchName: 'test-branch',
    userId: '123456789'
  })
  await populateAllocationQueue()
}

const populateAllocationQueue = async () => {
  for(let j = 0; j < allocationQueue.length; j++) {
    let allocation = allocationQueue[j];

    //some DOM manipulation

    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/users', { _id: allocation.createdBy })

    console.log('Never gets called - seems to hang on the above request without error message')
  }
}

setCurrentSandboxId('6');
```

Comment: Check the network tab in your console to see what's happening with your request. You will be sure if the request hangs or if it just never reaches there.

Comment: There is nothing displaying in the network tab for any of the requests unfortunately which i did find very strange.

Comment: Then something is broken; make sure you have XHR requests visible.